# HTTP PUT file and data

Tags: php, rest, curl

In my RESTful API say I have a picture the user can update via a PUT request.

And let's say each of these pictures has a custom name the user can assign them so they can easily browse them.

What I'd like to do is send a put request that contains the updated file AND the new name for the picture, but I'm not sure how to have PHP separate the updated file from the new name when reading from php://input

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place scalar parameters (i. e. old name, new name) into the query string.

Comment: I was considering doing this, but what if your image could have say... 20 options changed as well (e.g., place, time taken etc...)? Wouldn't a query string get quite long? Is using a query string the standard for this?

Comment: If you insist on sending the file in PUT form (as opposed to, say, POST with multipart/form-data), there's not much else you can use. You can employ custom headers with `X-` prefix, but that'd be stretching the protocol.

Comment: That is very bad practice - the URI is the target of the request. When you define out of band knowledge around special meanings of parts of the URI you introduce a very bad kind of coupling.

Comment: In the end I think I'm going to go the route of: posting/putting a json document to the server, and when they need to update the image and name, do something like PUT /images/update?name=name like Bit.ly does: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at AtomPub ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023 ), especially edit-media links. It does not quite give you what you want, but maybe you can adapt it.

It should be semantically ok to PUT a multipart doc to an atom entry where the first part of the multipart is an atom entry XML to update the title. The content element of that entry could point to the second multipart part (the image data) using a cid: URI ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392 )

The Slug header (also in RFC 5023) might also be a start to investigate.

There might also be some older headers around Content-Disposition: and Title: you might search for.

Another option is to just come up with a new resource that has the appropriate semantics and POST or PATCH a multipart or structured doc to that.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the url for the filename?

```
PUT /images/new_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format if you want to have multiple content types in the same request body is to use multipart mime to wrap them all into the same request body. Supporting something as complicated as multipart mime might be a bit hard to justify in this case though.

Comment: This would violate the meaning of PUT which is to update the resource with the request body.

Comment: @Jan: code is what code does. There's no meaning except for the implementation logic.

Comment: We must be talking about different things. I am talking about the semantics of HTTP and what can happen if you implement their semantics incorrectly on the server. E.g. GET /account/?action=delete. Remember Google Accelerator? http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/google_web_accelerator_hey_not_so_fast_an_alert_for_web_app_designers.php HTTP is an application layer interface - treat it like one.

Comment: @JanAlgermissen: I agree - but the question was regarding how to represent the data in a way that was readable through php://input - the fact that you shouldn't represent such data in the body of an image resource when you're using PUT is an entirely different matter. php://input contains the request body and multipart mime is the most correct way of mixing an image resource with a non image resource in the same request body.

Comment: Hmm - well then I'd suggest sending a multipart/related with an Atom entry as the root part which's content element references (via cid: ) the second part. (Described in my answer). That should not be too far off regarding AtomPubs definition of edit-media link relation.

Answer (score 0):

Upon consideration, I think what you need is a POST request with `multipart/form-data`. This allows for both file and some scalar data items, without the overhead of Base64 or URLEncode on the file data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SLUG header to do this:

> In other words the Slug header provides a means for a client to suggest the URI for a newly created resource.
>
> URIs can only use a limited set of characters, if the Slug uses characters outside the legal URI character set, then the server must escape those characters.
>
> Two or more clients might attempt to create a resource with the same Slug at the same time, the server must give each resource a unique URI, so the server may choose to decorate the slug with additional characters to ensure each resource is uniquely named.

**References**

- [Slug HTTP Header](https://blog.cdivilly.com/2016/03/01/slug-http-header/)
- [Text.Atom.Pub.Export](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/feed-0.3.11.1/docs/Text-Atom-Pub-Export.html)